# How can I get my animation to work in the other direction also?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have an angular slider whose default state is TRUE/OPEN.
I am able to use angular animations to slide it and it works only in one direction. I am not seeing that transition back. Any help would be great.

HTML:

```
<div class="container" [@slide]="slideOpen">
</div>
```

TS:

```
 import {animate, state, style, transition, trigger} from '@angular/animations';

    type SlideOpen = true|false;

    @Component({ 
    animations: [trigger(
          'slide',
          [
            state('true', style({transform: 'translateX(0px)'})),
            state('false', style({transform: 'translateX(-50%)'})),
            transition('* <=> *', animate(500))
          ])],
    })

    export class PanelInfo { 
        slideOpen = true;
    }
```

Comment: kindly accept and upvote the answer if it solved your purpose!

Comment: Hey @SouravDutta there is no actual difference in your solution and my question code, but I really appreciate your efforts and thank you for trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a sample example [**WORKING STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-slider-animation) similar to your code

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { animate, state, style, transition, trigger } from '@angular/animations';

type PaneType = 'left' | 'right';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-slide-panel',
  styleUrls: [ './slide-panel.component.scss' ],
  templateUrl: './slide-panel.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  animations: [
    trigger('slide', [
      state('left', style({ transform: 'translateX(0)' })),
      state('right', style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' })),
      transition('* => *', animate(300))
    ])
  ]
})
export class SlidePanelComponent {
  @Input() activePane: PaneType = 'left';
}
```

Hope this is helpful

Comment: nope this didn't help me, so your's is more like sliding multiple images. I would like to see with only one image, which will have a default state as visible, when the button is clicked, slides to the left side of the screen hiding the image and then on next click moves to the right and is visible.

Comment: I already went through that solution from where I used the idea to slide, but even in that case there are two panels and I am looking for something with only one panel slider, https://github.com/antonmoiseev/demo-slide-panel/blob/master/src/app/slide-panel/slide-panel.component.ts

Comment: @Bob got your point now check now, hopefully this solves your purpose. Check updated stackblitz :)